Why does LeaseInfo not match the XSD schema defined by Eureka?
The totality of the documentation for Eureka's logical "register" action, accomplished via an HTTP POST call, is here: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-REST-operations
It features an XML schema (!) that describes the payload of the POST operation (even when the payload is in JSON).
One of the elements is an (optional) leaseInfo element, described as follows:
<xsd:element name="leaseInfo">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>
            <!-- (optional) if you want to change the length of lease - default if 90 secs -->
            <xsd:element name="evictionDurationInSecs" minOccurs="0"  type="xsd:positiveInteger"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>

Looking at the corresponding Java LeaseInfo code, annotated with Jackson annotations governing serialization and deserialization, there are many other properties, and none that maps, via annotations or otherwise, to evictionDurationInSecs. How does a LeaseInfo, used via an InstanceInfo via, for example, the Jersey implementation, therefore, get serialized into the single evictionDurationInSecs property defined in this schema? Or, if the schema is wrong, which I suspect, what is actually required for an analogous POST operation? How would I find this out, short of reverse engineering all the code?
(From reverse engineering some of the code, I found this: https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/v2.0.3/eureka-client/src/main/java/com/netflix/discovery/converters/EurekaJacksonCodec.java#L309-L341. Maybe that simply is how it works, and there is no corresponding documentation? I've filed https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/issues/1563 to highlight the discrepancy.)
